# When "etc." is followed by "that", does it still require a comma?

Tags: punctuation, determiners, etc

Example:

> The lights, displays, sounds, shakers, etc. that attract the operators' attention to various situations (...)

Compared to:

> The lights, displays, sounds, shakers, etc., that attract the operators' attention to various situations (...)

In that context, if it wasn't for "etc.", there wouldn't have been a comma:

> The lights, displays, sounds, **and shakers that** attract the operators' attention to various situations (...)

... unlike if "which" was used instead of "that":

> The lights, displays, sounds, **and shakers, which** attract the operators' attention to various situations (...)

Comment: I would say, Yes : otherwise it looks like the end of a sentence and a capital letter is expected. But, stylewise, I suspect that there is no longer a need for a stop after etc, as we are all becoming 'less is more' about punctuation.

Comment: Stylewise as @Nigel said, the dot could be avoided. Even when the dot is there, comma may avoided for two reasons. 1) the sentence continues in lower case, leaving no ambiguity. 2) before a connecting 'that' comma is usually not placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is a matter of style. There are a few choices:

1. Use a comma, even though you normally wouldn't. This might be to avoid the appearance of the sentence ending—but then continuing.
2. Don't use a comma, because you normally wouldn't, and ignore the fact that it looks a bit strange in the context of the sentence as a whole.
3. Rephrase the sentence, replacing *etc.* with something like *and so on*.
4. Use the actual non-shortened word: [*etcetera*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/etcetera) (or *et cetera*; unfortunately, this is another style choice).

---

To give a specific example of just one style guide, here is what [*The Chicago Manual of Style (17th ed.), 6.20*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec020.html), says:

> The abbreviation *etc.* (*et cetera*, literally “and others of the same kind”) and such equivalents as *and so forth* and *and the like* are preceded by a comma; they are followed by a comma only if required by the surrounding text. This small departure from the recommendation in previous editions treats such terms as equivalent to the final element in a series (see 6.19). (According to a more traditional usage, such terms were often set off by two commas.) In formal prose, Chicago prefers to limit the abbreviation *etc.* to parentheses, notes, and tabular matter …
>
> The map was far from complete (lacking many of the streets, alleys, etc. seen in earlier iterations).
>       The philosopher’s population studies, classic textbooks, stray notes, and so forth were found in the attic.
>
> *but*
>
> For a discussion of periods, commas, and the like, see chapter 6.
>
> The abbreviation *et al.* (*et alia* [neut.], *et alii* [masc.], or *et aliae* [fem.], literally “and others”), whether used in regular text or (more often) in bibliographical references, should be treated like *etc.* If *et al.* follows a single item, however (e.g., “Jones et al.”), it requires no preceding comma. (Nor is a preceding comma required in the rare case that *etc.* follows a single item.) Note that neither *etc.* nor *et al.* is italicized in normal prose (see the first example above).

If you strictly follow that guidance, *etc.* wouldn't be used in the sentence in the question at all, because it's not present in parentheses, a note, or tabular matter.  But if you *were* to use it, the guidance would be to not use a comma, since the surrounding text wouldn't normally have one.

However, you might not choose to follow the *Chicago* guidance.

---

There is no universal rule. Pick one of the above approaches and apply it consistently.

Comment: The 16th addition, which I've been using for a while, has commas before and after etc. when used in a series.

Comment: @StuW They changed their guidance in the most recent edition, although they don't say why.

Comment: @Stu W It's very useful to know that (a) style guides do take note of changing preferences in the real world, (b) such issues have no 'one right' answer, and (c) keeping abreast of such changes in preferred styles (17 different editions of CMOS alone) is far from being a piece of cake. Thank you.